# ComboBox in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, combobox

I can't access to combo box's value for using  in GridView.

GridView something like this:

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="cmb" FieldName="cmb" Name="cmb"
                VisibleIndex="4">
                <DataItemTemplate>
               <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"
                      ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                   EnableSynchronization="True" TextField="rolAd" ValueField="rolid"
                        ValueType="System.Int32">
                    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                </DataItemTemplate>
           </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

when I accessing to all fields with the following those codes,it's coming as null those datas with combobox.

```
 List<object> selectedValues;

    private void GetSelectedValues()
    {
        List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (GridViewColumn column in ASPxGridView1.Columns)
           if (column is GridViewDataColumn)
                fieldNames.Add(((GridViewDataColumn)column).FieldName);
        selectedValues = ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues(fieldNames.ToArray());
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to the combobox in your c# code. How were you trying to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might give this a try

```
GridView_ID.FindControl("ASPxComboBox1")
```

to retrieve the ComboBox